# pivot error when doing a defined variable in IN

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot, oracle-sqldeveloper

Can anyone tell me why I get "invalid number of arguments" message when I do this:

```
define mb1= ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE,'MM')-1);

select *
from
(select COLLECTOR
,Month
,low_activity_days
from dwh_prod.low_activity_days_collect_t) src
pivot
(
sum(low_activity_days)
for month in (&mb1)
) piv;
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Missing comma

```
define mb1= ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE,'MM'), -1);
```